# Express middleware not capturing request events for socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm using **Express** (v4.17.3), **Socket.io**, and Node.Js's **http** module. I'm adding a middleware for **express** to capture all incoming requests but that's failing.

I'll first show the code I'm using and the output then explain my understanding/expectation of the output (I'm new to Node and all the mentioned libraries so perhaps I'm missing something)

First of all, below is the code I'm referring to. Using **Express**'s middleware I'm trying to capture all the incoming requests and log them, and doing the same for the http `on("request")`. However, requests going to **socket.io** aren't captured by the middleware.

```
// Express
const express = require("express");
const app = express()
// Socket
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const {Server} = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server)

// Want to listen to all incoming requests using the middleware (this doesn't work)
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(`Express request = ${req.url}`)
    next()
})

// Listening to all incoming requests (this works)
server.on("request", (req, res)=>{
    console.log(`Http request = ${req.url}`) 
})

server.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port 8080`)
})
```

output when I GET /

```
Express request = /

Http request = /
Http request = /socket.io/socket.io.js
Http request = /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O0va...
Http request = /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O0va24A&sid=c...
Http request = /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O0va24F&sid=c...
Http request = /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O0va27x&sid=c...
```

My expected output is to have equal logs for the middleware `app.use()` and `on("request")` ("Express request = " & "Http request = ")

**My understanding:**

1- When I add a middleware for **express** as in the code below, any incoming requests should be captured here first before going anywhere else. (correct?)

`app.use((req,res,next)=>{...})`

2- When I'm passing the **express app** as an argument to http's`createServer`, that the **express app** will be treated as a listener and any `request` events will be passed to it.  (correct?)

`const server = require('http').createServer(app);`

So if my understanding is correct, why aren't all the requests captured by the request event passed to the middleware as well?

Comment: io.sockets middlewares are not related to the express server requests, web sockets use their own protocol, ws:// not http:// , so you need to place your websocket middlewares in `io.use()` not in `app.use()`, at least that's how I've always been using `socket.io` without problems!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal.  Socket.io puts itself in front of express (or any other listener for incoming requests on the http server) so that it takes the request before Express sees it.  Thus, Express (or it's middleware) never see any socket.io connection requests.

Socket.io has its [own middleware layer](https://socket.io/docs/v4/middlewares/) that you can use to participate in the initialization of socket.io requests.

Or, you can register for incoming socket.io connections (to be called after they are already connected) with the `io.on('connection', ...)` event handler.

> When I add a middleware for express as in the code below, any incoming requests should be captured here first before going anywhere else. (correct?)

That is true except for code that registers directly request handlers right on the http server and inserts itself before Express in the listener chain, thus preventing Express from seeing any requests that are destined for socket.io.

> When I'm passing the express app as an argument to http'screateServer, that the express app will be treated as a listener and any request events will be passed to it. (correct?)

That is true.  But socket.io jumps in front of Express and takes/hides any requests it wants so that Express never sees them.

---

If you're curious, here's the [socket.io code](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/be3d7f0f1f9a5105a926c18d17bf2613676ce98b/lib/index.ts#L447) that jumps in line to the front of all listeners for the http server thus bypassing the express listener:

```
attachServe(srv) {
    debug("attaching client serving req handler");
    const evs = srv.listeners("request").slice(0);
    srv.removeAllListeners("request");
    srv.on("request", (req, res) => {
        if (this.clientPathRegex.test(req.url)) {
            this.serve(req, res);
        }
        else {
            for (let i = 0; i < evs.length; i++) {
                evs[i].call(srv, req, res);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It grabs all the existing listeners into an array.  Then, it removes them all.  Then, it registers for the `request` event itself and, if it is a socket.io request, then it does not call the prior listeners.  If it is not a socket.io prefix, then it manually calls the prior listeners.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the thorough explanation, that makes sense now. And yeah I was just checking the source code for this part, definitely helpful. 
The only part I don't understand is that if socket.io gets the socket.io request and doesn't call the subsequent listeners, why can we still get the request if we add `server.on("request", ... )` as shown in the code I shared in the question? I tried to check inside the `this.serve(req,res)` function but I can't seem to find why is that behavior

Comment: @YousefGamal  - Well, if you do `server.on("request", ...)` AFTER you've hooked up socket.io, then the above code does not bypass it.  But, the usually way to configure Express involves hooking it up to the server before you configure socket.io so socket.io goes last and then inserts itself first.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to log the messages sent on socket.

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => { socket.on('chat message', (msg) => { console.log('message: ' + msg); }); });
```